# @ServiceActivator without @MessageEndpoint in Spring Integration annotation config

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I am trying to use replace xml configuration to java/annotation based one for a simple tcp server with Spring Integration (version 4.0.6).
I got it working as following using @MessageEndpoint. The problem is that for some reason class that is annotated with @MessageEndpoint has to be static. I can't inject beans in it because of that to do something useful.
From what I understand, it should be possible to use @ServiceActivator without @MessageEndpoint, but I couldn't figure out how.

Here is what I have right now. In the comments you can see what xml part I tried to replace.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class TcpServerContextConfiguration {
//    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
//    type="server"
//    port="5678"
//    single-use="true"
//    so-timeout="10000"/>

    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory crLfServer() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(5678);
        factory.setSingleUse(true);
        factory.setSoTimeout(10000);
        return factory;
    }

//    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
//    connection-factory="crLfServer"
//    request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"/>

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway gatewayCrLf() {
        TcpInboundGateway gateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(crLfServer());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(serverBytes2StringChannel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel serverBytes2StringChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

//    <int:channel id="toSA" />

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel toSA() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

//    <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
//    ref="echoService"
//    method="test"/>
//
//    <bean id="echoService"
//    class="com.posera.www.poseraStats.site.EchoService" />

    @MessageEndpoint
    public static class Echo {

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toSA")
        public String echoService(String req) {
            return "echo:" + req;
        }
    }


//    <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
//    input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
//    output-channel="toSA"/>

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel="serverBytes2StringChannel", outputChannel="toSA")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer serverBytes2String() {
        return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
    }
}
```

So I tried the following code with @MessageEndpoint, but it fails:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toSA")
public String echoService(String req) {
    return "echo:" + req;
}
```

I guess the answer I am looking for should something like this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toSA")
public MessageHandler newEchoService() {
}
```

But I have no idea which implementation of MessageHandler interface I need to use for input channel which is String at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bean classes have to be static or top-level classes.

Static classes are ok, but you have to declare a bean instance to autowire or inject other beans into the instance...

```
@Bean Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

public static class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;

    ...
}
```

Or if you annotate your `TcpServerContextConfiguration` with `@MessageEndpoint`, you can just use the `@ServiceActivator` style without the `@Bean`. If you upgrade to 4.3.x (currently 4.3.5), `@MessageEndpoint` is no longer needed at the class level.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks a lot for such a quick answer. I had a feeling that you will answer it :)

Comment: Adding `@MessageEndpoint` to TcpServerContextConfiguration helped. Thanks a lot. But for my understanding in the future: is there a way to use `@ServiceActivator`without `@MessageEndpoint` as I described in the question?

Comment: As I said `@MessageEndpoint` is no longer needed from 4.3 onwards. Prior to that, it was required for POJO `@ServiceActivator`; the `@Bean` style of `@ServiceActivator` has to be of type `MessageHandler`. To use that style, you should subclass `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` and implement `handleRequestMessage()`. The output channel needs to be specified in the handler, not in the `@ServiceActivator`. There are two beans, the consumer endpoint and the handler. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans).

Comment: Makes more sense to me now. Thanks.